# devexpress xaf database from SQL SERVER to POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, devexpress, code-first, npgsql

I'm trying to execute the most basic XAF example from devexpress website with PostgreSQL. How can I do it? I've added Entityframework6.Npgsql (from https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/) to sampleErp.Module project and changed the file app.config in project sampleErp.Win. I've also added EntityFramework6.Npgsql to the GAC.

Here is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections> 
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>    
<appSettings>
  <add key="Modules" value="" />
  <add key="NewVersionServer" value="" />
  <add key="EnableDiagnosticActions" value="False" />
  <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EasyTestConnectionString" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=mobi03xaf;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="ConnectionStringEF" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=mobi03xaf;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=mobi03xaf;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql" />
  <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
        invariant="Npgsql" 
       support="FF" 
       description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"
       type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="eXpressAppFramework" value="3" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I've also installed Npgsql.dll to the GAC by command `gacutil /i path\npgsql.dll.`

Here is log of the command:
gacutil /l

Npgsql, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL.

But when I try execute project, I'm getting the following error:

```
InnerException:

        Type:       InvalidOperationException
        Message:    The Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
        Data:       0 entries
        Stack trace:
```

How can I solve this problem?